# Python: Universal XML parser

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing, urllib

I'm trying to make simple Python 3 program to read weather information from XML web source, convert it into Python-readable object (maybe dictionary) and process it (for example visualize multiple observations into graph).
Source of data is national weather service's (direct translation) xml file at link provided in code.
What's different from typical XML parsing related question in Stack Overflow is that there are repetitive tags without in-tag identificator (`<station>` tags in my example) and some with (1st line, `<observations timestamp="14568.....">`). Also I would like to try parse it straight from website, not local file. Of course, I could create local temporary file too.
What I have so far, is simply loading script, that gives string containing xml code for both forecast and latest weather observations.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
#Read 4-day forecast
forecast= urlopen("http://www.ilmateenistus.ee/ilma_andmed/xml/forecast.php").read().decode("iso-8859-1")
#Get current weather
observ=urlopen("http://www.ilmateenistus.ee/ilma_andmed/xml/observations.php").read().decode("iso-8859-1")
```

**Shortly,** I'm looking for as universal as possible way to parse XML to  Python-readable object (such as dictionary/JSON or list) while preserving all of the information in XML-file.

P.S I prefer standard Python 3 module such as xml, which I didn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `xmltodict` package for simple conversion of XML structure to Python dict: https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict

Comment: Thanks, although I wanted to avoid non-standard libraries because I had never installed using pip before. But I got it working.